# My ps1 line is changed when i logout and re login?

Tags: bash, ps1

I have this in `.bash_profile`

```
if [ -n "$TMUX" ]; then
    # called inside tmux session, do tmux things
    . ~/.profile

fi
# Trigger ~/.bashrc commands
. ~/.bashrc

# ----------------------------------
# Colors
# ----------------------------------
NOCOLOR='\033[0m'
RED='\033[0;31m'
GREEN='\033[0;32m'
ORANGE='\033[0;33m'
BLUE='\033[0;34m'
PURPLE='\033[0;35m'
CYAN='\033[0;36m'
LIGHTGRAY='\033[0;37m'
DARKGRAY='\033[1;30m'
LIGHTRED='\033[1;31m'
LIGHTGREEN='\033[1;32m'
YELLOW='\033[1;33m'
LIGHTBLUE='\033[1;34m'
LIGHTPURPLE='\033[1;35m'
LIGHTCYAN='\033[1;36m'
WHITE='\033[1;37m'
```

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
#[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
   #prompt_color='\[\033[;32m\]'
    prompt_color='\[\033[;31m\]'
   #info_color='\[\033[1;34m\]'
    info_color='\[\033[1;32m\]'
    #prompt_symbol=
     prompt_symbol=@
    if [ "$EUID" -eq 0 ]; then # Change prompt colors for root user
    prompt_color='\[\033[;94m\]'
    info_color='\[\033[1;32m\]'
    #prompt_symbol=
         prompt_symbol=@
    fi

    # PS1=$prompt_color'┌───[\D{%d/%m-%Y} - \A]\[$(tput sgr0)\] - ${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)──}('$info_color'\u${prompt_symbol}\h'$prompt_color')-[\[\033[0;1m\]\w'$prompt_color']\n'$prompt_color'└─'$info_color'\$\[\033[0m\] '
    PS1="$prompt_color┌───${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)──}[${info_color}\u${RED}@${info_color}\h${prompt_color}]-[\[\033[0;1m\]\w${prompt_color}]\n${prompt_color}└─${info_color}#\[\033[0m\] "
    # BackTrack red prompt
    #PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;31m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls, less and man, and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
    alias diff='diff --color=auto'
    alias ip='ip --color=auto'

    export LESS_TERMCAP_mb=$'\E[1;31m'     # begin blink
    export LESS_TERMCAP_md=$'\E[1;36m'     # begin bold
    export LESS_TERMCAP_me=$'\E[0m'        # reset bold/blink
    export LESS_TERMCAP_so=$'\E[01;33m'    # begin reverse video
    export LESS_TERMCAP_se=$'\E[0m'        # reset reverse video
    export LESS_TERMCAP_us=$'\E[1;32m'     # begin underline
    export LESS_TERMCAP_ue=$'\E[0m'        # reset underline
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -l'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'
alias dfh='df -h'
alias cp='/usr/local/bin/cp -gR'
alias mv='/usr/local/bin/mv -g'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi

#Screenfetch
#if [ -f /usr/bin/screenfetch ]; then screenfetch; fi
```

Why is that?

Comment: I wonder if there is a path issue. Can you change `if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then` to `if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && /usr/bin/tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then`. Or have you done any other troubleshooting to make sure your if conditions are firing? An example would be writing a temp files with the date in them into /tmp/ somewhere.

Comment: Hello! I tryed to changed it, but the effect was the same.

Comment: I have tried the following: 

1. ```mv .bashrc .bashrc.bak```
2. ```cp /etc/skel/.bashrc .bashrc```

and readded my PS1 color, that gave the same result

Comment: Did you add just the line that changes the prompt and not all of the extra if/else stuff?

Answer (score 0):

There is probably another answer with this information in it already, but I am just going to answer and not look for it.

## .bash_profile vs. .bashrc

So, `.bash_profile` is executed when Bash is invoked as an interactive login shell. `.bashrc` is executed when bash is invoked as a **non-login** shell.

You can either add your prompt stuff to `~/.bash_profile` or, source `~/.bash_profile` from `~/.bashrc` <- this is pretty common.

### Example of sourcing `~/.bashrc` from `~/.bash_profile`

```
# ~/.bash_profile

# some lines of stuff

if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

## Further troubleshooting

The file `/etc/profile` is also sourced at some point but I believe it is before hand. I have seen some weird things happen though we people modifying this file.

If the above doesn't work could you update your question with the contents of your `~/.bash*` files?

Comment: Hrmm.. Actually, I read your question more carefully and realized that you mentioned "everything is lightgreen" - Where is the `$color_prompt` var set? Could it be that it is not set when you login and the script is evaluated?

Comment: I have updatet my first post